# Refinablestring Date Column Range Results using Search Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, date-time, search-api

We have a Document Library in SharePoint Online with  `Date Column`  and  it was mapped to `RefinableString00` Managed property. currently we are getting the search result using the below api url

```
"/_api/search/query?querytext='invoce'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Path,Url,Title,RefinableString00,RefinableString02,RefinableString03,RefinableString04,RefinableString05,RefinableString06,RefinableString144,RefinableString145,RefinableString01'&sourceid='xxx-xx-xx-xxxx'&rowlimit=500"
```

I am getting the value for the `RefinableString00`  as `3/20/2019 5:00:00 AM`
Now i want to get the search result based on the `RefinableString00`

For example last 3 months,6 months, 1 year and 2 years etc...

Can anyone help me on this..

Comment: For starters, your should be using RefinableDate for this. Date fields can be queried with date operators like `today` etc.

Comment: Is there any way to do the querying with the refinableString

Comment: Not if you want to use the date functions. You are using the wrong data type. Just change it.